# Swift: Prevent double values from removing decimals

Tags: swift

When i convert String values to Double, if the decimals are zeros (for example 10.0,11.0 etc), swift automatically rounds the number and removes the decimals. Is there a way to prevent swift from removing the zeros after the decimal point?

Comment: Isn't `10 == 10.0`?

Comment: @Kamran it is. my problem is that the backend expects a double value. when i send 10, even though it's a double, it gives me errors. but when i send a number with decimals, say 10.1, it works perfectly. is it possible to do anything about it in swift, or should the backend handle this?

Comment: How do you send value to the backend?

Comment: @user28434 i send a double value, but its rounded, so the backend recognizes it as an integer. when it's not rounded, it works perfectly

Comment: How do you send *double* value? What protocol/message format/etc. Provide the code and an example of a message you're sending to the backend.

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a try in the online compiler that repl.it provides. But it doesn't act the way you said. I wrote the following code:

```
let x = Double("10")!
print(x)
```

And the output I got was:

```
10.0
```